# Matter device is stuck at "Connecting device to Google Home..." when commissioning using Google Home app, but is partially added anyway

Tags: google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

I'm developing a Matter device and have a Vendor ID issued by the CSA and validated in Google's Developer console. Also we have a product ID published in the DCL. I'm testing a Matter device on my developer console linked account in the Google Home App (GHA) and getting most of the way through onboarding. It gets stuck forever at "Connecting device to Google Home" and seems to never time-out. After manually exiting, the device sort-of appears in the Google Home App, but it's missing its correct device name and vendor info. It shows up named "bridge" (in my case we are building a bridge/aggregator device).

Testing using a Nest Audio as the Matter controller and Samsung Galaxy S21 phone. Device is built on the Espressif SDK.

[screenshot: Connecting device to Google Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qX7U.jpg)

What could be causing this failure?

I've verified the VID and PID and device Type ID (0xe) are correct and match in the DCL, Google console and the advertisement on the device.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up. Can you please open a bug in [Public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) and share the logs and screenshots necessary for debugging. I’m going to follow up with the internal teams and update you through the issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but it got resolved when I used the latest code from the master branch of the [Google Home sample app](https://github.com/google-home/sample-apps-for-matter-android). I recommend checking out the master branch in Android Studio, running it, and then attempting to add your Matter device.